# QuickBooks IPP Error code="4000" Parse error, query contains invalid string

Tags: quickbooks

We recently made the switch from QBXML to the IPP v3.0 integration to beat the deadline. It has been fairly successful except for one client. This client appears to have a problem with their QBO file. If I log into the IPP site using the users credentials and try and use the API explorer with very basic queries such as "select * from account"

Request URI: [https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/[their](https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/%5btheir) realm ID here]/query?query=select%20%2A%20from%20account

The API explorer returns

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3"time="2014-06-12T16:16:51.093Z">
  <Fault type="Validation">
    <Error code="4000">
      <Message>Parse error, query contains invalid string</Message>
    </Error>
  </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

It returns this error no matter what item I try to query etc. I submitted support tickets and the response I received was :

*"Nimisha asked me to look at this and I don't know what is going wrong.
Requests work in V2, but not V3.
We will need to escalate this to the QBO group. Nimisha will be in touch if we have any other questions."*

I've never heard back and the end user is very frustrated as they have been without integration for over a month. Has anyone ran into this problem or have any idea what would be causing the problem. I'm not sure who to contact as the IPP support seems limited to support tickets.